# Parse a url with # in GO

Tags: http, go, request

So I'm receiving a request to my server that looks a little something like this

```
http://localhost:8080/#access_token=tokenhere&scope=scopeshere
```

and I can't seem to find a way to parse the token from the url.

If the # were a ? I could just parse it a standard query param.

I tried to just getting everything after the / and even the full URL, but with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:

So I've solved the issue now, and the correct answer is you can't really do it in GO. So I made a simple package that will do it on the browser side and then send the token back to the server.

Check it out if you're trying to do local twitch API stuff in GO:

https://github.com/SimplySerenity/twitchOAuth

Comment: It looks like you're using an OAuth2 system. Perhaps you should use the authorization code grant, rather than implicit.

Comment: @TimCooper Maybe I should have been a little clearer the app is actually run locally on the users computer, and just opens an http server to capture the redirect with the token.

Comment: "So I'm receiving a request to my server that looks a little something like this `http://localhost:8080/#access_token`". No your are not. Fragments are not sent and thus not received.

Comment: Fix the client to send the stuff after the `#` after a `?` instead. It's not really a server side problem, just a bad client failing to use HTTP appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anchor part is not even (generally) sent by a client to the server.

Eg, browsers don't send it.

Answer (score 5):

For parse urls use the golang **net/url** package: https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/

OBS: You should use the Authorization header for send auth tokens.

Example code with extracted data from your example url:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "net/url"
)

func main() {
    // Your url with hash
    s := "http://localhost:8080/#access_token=tokenhere&scope=scopeshere"
    // Parse the URL and ensure there are no errors.
    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ---> here is where you will get the url hash #
    fmt.Println(u.Fragment)
    fragments, _ := url.ParseQuery(u.Fragment)
    fmt.Println("Fragments:", fragments)
    if fragments["access_token"] != nil {
      fmt.Println("Access token:", fragments["access_token"][0])
    } else {
      fmt.Println("Access token not found")
    }


    // ---> Others data get from URL:
     fmt.Println("\n\nOther data:\n")
    // Accessing the scheme is straightforward.
    fmt.Println("Scheme:", u.Scheme)
    // The `Host` contains both the hostname and the port,
    // if present. Use `SplitHostPort` to extract them.
    fmt.Println("Host:", u.Host)
    host, port, _ := net.SplitHostPort(u.Host)
    fmt.Println("Host without port:", host)
    fmt.Println("Port:",port)
    // To get query params in a string of `k=v` format,
    // use `RawQuery`. You can also parse query params
    // into a map. The parsed query param maps are from
    // strings to slices of strings, so index into `[0]`
    // if you only want the first value.
    fmt.Println("Raw query:", u.RawQuery)
    m, _ := url.ParseQuery(u.RawQuery)
    fmt.Println(m)
}

// part of this code was get from: https://gobyexample.com/url-parsing
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately (at least as far as I can tell) I don't actually have access to the full URL from the server request. 

I have a function that is being called on any request to "/", but the URL fragments seem to be completely empty when the function is called.

Comment: @SimplySerenity that's to be expected. The anchor portion of a URL is client-side only and should not be sent to the server.

Comment: This helped me in the case of a [manual login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#logindialog) for a Desktop app, where I'm using a [webview](https://github.com/webview/webview) to open the login url and then parsing the fragment in the redirect. Thank you!